# I'm trying to capture data from a Signup form to a database in php, the information does successfully get to the database but it skips the errors

Tags: php

I have been trying to capture a registration form to my database. It captures the data but it doesn't go through my errors or 'if' statements. Even if I submit an empty form, the data will go through on to my database and it will just be empty rows. So, I'm trying to stop that from happening, and force the form to go through error handlers first before signing up the user.

The code inside includes/register-inc.php is as follows...

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    // Grabbing the data
    $name = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $surname = filter_var($_POST["surname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $gender = filter_var($_POST["gender"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $race = filter_var($_POST["race"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = strtolower($_POST["email"]);
    $username = filter_var($_POST["username"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $pwd = strip_tags($_POST["password"]);
    $pwdRepeat = $_POST["retype_password"];
    $joined = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    
    if(empty($name)) {
        $errorMsg[0][] = "Name required!"; 
    }
    if(empty($lastname)) {
        $errorMsg[1][] = "Last name required!"; 
    }
    if(empty($gender)) {
        $errorMsg[2][] = "Please select gender!"; 
    }
    if(empty($race)) {
        $errorMsg[3][] = "Please select your race!"; 
    }
    if(empty($email)) {
        $errorMsg[4][] = "Email required!"; 
    }
    if(empty($username)) {
        $errorMsg[5][] = "Username required!"; 
    }
    if(empty($pwd)) {
        $errorMsg[6][] = "Password required!"; 
    }
    if(strlen($pwd) < 8) {
        $errorMsg[6][] = "Password must be at least 8 characters"; 
    }
    if($pwd !== $pwdRepeat) {
        $errorMsg[7][] = "Password don't match!"; 
    }
    
    // 1. connect to the database
    $pdo = require_once '../classes/DB.php';

    // 2. construct SQL (insert) statement
    $query = 'INSERT INTO users (name, surname, gender, race, email, username, password, joined) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

    // 3. prepare (insert) statement
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

    // 4. execute prepared statement
    $stmt->execute(array($name, $surname, $gender, $race, $email, $username, $pwd, $joined));

    // 5. calling the lastInsertId() method of the PDO object
    $register_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
    echo 'You have successfully registered as register id ' . $register_id . '. <br>You may proceed to <a href="../login.php">LOGIN</a>.';

}
```

and the code inside register.php is as follows...

````
<form action="includes/register-inc.php" method="post">
                <?php 
                    if(isset($errorMsg[0])) {
                        foreach($errorMsg[0] as $nameErrors) {
                            echo '<p class="error-msg">.$nameErrors.</p>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Type your firstname(s)" value="">
                
                <?php 
                    if(isset($errorMsg[1])) {
                        foreach($errorMsg[1] as $surnameErrors) {
                            echo '<p class="error-msg">.$nameErrors.</p>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Type your surname" value="">
                
                <div class="row">
                    <?php 
                        if(isset($errorMsg[2])) {
                            foreach($errorMsg[2] as $genderErrors) {
                                echo '<p class="error-msg">.$nameErrors.</p>';
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                    <select name="gender" class="gender">
                        <option value="0" selected disabled>Select your Gender</option> 
                        <option value="male">Male</option> 
                        <option value="female">Female</option> 
                    </select>
                    
                    <?php 
                    if(isset($errorMsg[3])) {
                        foreach($errorMsg[3] as $raceErrors) {
                            echo '<p class="error-msg">.$nameErrors.</p>';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                    <select name="race" class="race">
                        <option value="0" selected disabled>Select your Race</option> 
                        <option value="african">African</option>
                        <option value="asian">Asian</option> 
                        <option value="caucasian">Caucasian</option>
                        <option value="mixed-race">Mixed Race</option> 
                        <option value="indian">Indian</option> 
                        <option value="other">Other</option> 
                    </select>
                </div>
                
                <?php 
                    if(isset($errorMsg[4])) {
                        foreach($errorMsg[4] as $emailErrors) {
                            echo '<p class="error-msg">.$emailErrors.</p>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Type your email address" value="">
                
                <?php 
                    if(isset($errorMsg[5])) {
                        foreach($errorMsg[5] as $usernameErrors) {
                            echo '<p class="error-msg">.$usernameErrors.</p>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Create username" value="" autocomplete="off">
                
                <?php 
                    if(isset($errorMsg[6])) {
                        foreach($errorMsg[6] as $passwordErrors) {
                            echo '<p class="error-msg">.$passwordErrors.</p>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Create password">
                
                <?php 
                    if(isset($errorMsg[7])) {
                        foreach($errorMsg[7] as $matchErrors) {
                            echo '<p class="error-msg">.$matchErrors.</p>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                <input type="password" name="retype_password" placeholder="Re-type password">
                    <div class="text-white">
                        <div class="link-white">
                            <label for="terms">I accept the <a href="terms.php">Terms and Conditions</a>.</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="accepted">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="contact-btn2">Register</button>
            </form> ```

I can see how to fix the issue... I am able to capture data into my database but it is skipping the errors. Even if I submit an empty form it still captures the form. What can I or should do to prevent this from happening?
````

Comment: You're creating the error array, but never bailing if it has any values.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what that means... I'm still a beginner and I'm teaching myself without prior knowledge...

Comment: You create all of the errors for `$errorMsg`,but you insert the values no matter if it's hit any of the error lines or not. You need to see if `$errorMsg` is empty before attempting to insert.